# Create a function that sorts struct with ints in ascending order?

Tags: c++

I am creating a program that calculates the average of students scores ( already did it ), but I also need to sort them in ascending order ( 1,2,3,4,5,6). The only thing is I have these values stored inside a struct and I need a function that puts them in ascending order. I also need to put it all together so the format should be like Student Name -- Student Score

```
                  Austin          30
                  Tom             20 
                  Emma            10
                  =============================
                  Average: 20
                  List: [10,20,30]
```

Here is my program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct student
{
    int score;
    std::string name;
};

void sortarr(student &a);
void sortarr(student &a) {
    std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    
    for(int i{0}; i <= size; i++)
        std::cout <<"The sorted vector is: " << a.score << " ";
}

void average_score(std::vector <student> &arr,int size);
void average_score(std::vector <student> &arr, int size) {
    float average {0};
    
    for(int i{0}; i < size; i++) {
        average += arr[i].score;
    }
    
    std::cout << "The average is: " << average / size << std::endl;

}

int main() {
    
    int n;
    std::cout <<"Enter Size: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<student> test_scores(n);

    int i = 0;
    
    student s;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Enter Student " << i+1 << " Name and Test Score: ";
            std::cin >> s.name >> s.score;
    
            test_scores[i] = s;
    
    }
    
    average_score(test_scores,3);
    
}
```

If you can reformat my program a better way and make it run more efficiently that would be great as well.

Comment: If you have working code, you should better ask that question at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Your `sortarr` function is broken in a few ways. It takes a single `student` by reference, not a collection of them. The `student` struct doesn't have `begin` or `end` methods, although that'll be irrelevant once you've fixed the signature. The for loop uses an undeclared, uninitialized variable `size`, and then in the body it doesn't actually depend on the index variable `i` in any way.

Comment: Furthermore, your `average_score` function doesn't need to take a `size` argument and in fact probably shouldn't since it only creates the possibility of an error if the value of `size` doesn't match the value of `arr.size()`.

Answer (score 2):

To sort a `vector<student>` in ascending order by the member `score`, you can write:

```
std::ranges::sort(arr, std::less{}, &student::score);
```

---

If you can't use c++20, you can write:

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 
          [](auto const & a, auto const & b) 
          {
              return a.score < b.score;
          });
```

Comment: You could also write `bool operator<(const student& rhs)` as a `student` member function.

Comment: @NathanPierson I'm not a fan of that, unless `score` is the natural default ordering for `student`s (and `name` might be more appropriate here).

Comment: Oh, that's a good point, I'd only been thinking of the immediate use case.

Comment: @cigien I am still a little confused on where to put these lines at? Do I create a function and then put the line inside of it or? sorry I am new to programming and am confused.

Comment: @austinvan295 No, just replace your call to `sort` with one of these lines.

Comment: @cigien Nvm I got it! I created a sortArray function that took in the parameters std::vector<student> &a; and then sorted it by using your second code block. I am just curious why wouldn't just sort work by itself? Why do I have to use auto const and is that lamda expression? also why is it returning a.score < b.score

Comment: @austinvan295 This should be covered in the material you're using. Look up `<algorithm>`s, lambdas, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>




std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> m;

void fillMap();
void sortarr(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> a);


void average_score(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> arr);


int main() {

    fillMap();
    sortarr(m);
    average_score(m);
}

void sortarr(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> a)
{
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());

    for (auto i : a)
        std::cout << i.first << " ";
}
void fillMap()
{
    unsigned lengthMap{}, score{};
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter the length of your map: ";
    std::cin >> lengthMap;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthMap; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the score: ";
        std::cin >> score;
        std::cout << "Enter the name: ";
        std::cin >> name;
        m.push_back(std::make_pair(score, name));
    }
}
void average_score(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> arr) {
    float average{ 0 };

    for (auto i:arr) {
        average += i.first;
    }

    std::cout << "The average is: " << average / m.size() << '\n';

}
```

using STL is much easier and efficient than using structs because many algorithms are available in STL. That's said, if you declare a function, it's better to define it after `main()`. I've reorganised your code to be more readable

Comment: `fillMap` and `lengthMap` are kind of inappropriate names when `m` isn't any kind of map.

Comment: not quite, it's something like map behind the scene, but using this (with vector) let me use sort :D

Comment: It's like a map, but it's not a map. If you'd wanted to, you could have gone all the way and written a `std::map<std::string, int>` that actually was a map from names to scores. However, I think this would be a poor approach. I don't know the full scope of the asker's project, but student data like this is a natural candidate for an object-oriented approach where you keep relevant data bundled together into structs for readability. ETA: Although yes, a `map` keyed off strings still wouldn't be sorted by score. Points about honesty in naming and OO design remain.

Comment: I prefer using some STL instead of using struct here, because he's using sort. and for readability, it's simple to mention at the top of the file a comment saying //I'm using this container to store a score and a name. using struct it would more complicated comparing to STL

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that compares (orders) two structs and returns the `bool` result:

```
typedef std::pair<int, std::string> Item; // Makes typing and reading easier.
bool Compare_By_Score(const Item& a, const Item& b)
{
  return a.first < b.first;
}
```

To sort a vector:

```
std::vector<Item> database;
std::sort(database.begin(), database.end(), Compare_By_Score);
```

To change the ordering of the `database`, write and supply a different ordering function.